# Android Html.fromhtml() + SpannableString

Tags: android, html, textview

I have `html` string and `SpannableString` in this string and I put it all in the `TextView`, and the problem is in `SpannableString`, it's not shown in `Html.fromhtml()`. How can I show `SpannableString` in `Html.fromHtml()`? Is it possible?

```
    for(int index = 0; index < l.length; index++){ // have3d() return SpannableString
            x += "<font color=\"green\">" + have3d(title[index]) + " </font> <br />" + l[index] + "<br/><br/>";
            if(index == l.length-1){
                x += "<font color=\"green\">" + title[index] + " </font> <br />" + l[index] + "<br/>";
            }   
        }
mСinema.setText(Html.fromHtml(x));
```

Answer (score 26):

`Html.fromHtml` returns a `Spanned`, that you can convert to a `SpannableString` this way:

```
SpannableString text = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(x));
```

And then set it by calling:

```
mcinema.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: What does x contain?

Comment: use HtmlCompat now

Comment: thanks man, this enabled me to mix html and spannable